# Find an equation to the tangent line to the curve at the given point

Tags: calculus, parametric, tangent-line

\begin{align}
x &= \cos t + \cos 2t, &   y &= \sin t + \sin 2t,  & \left(−1, 1\right)
\end{align}

Using the above information I found that $\;\frac{dy}{dx}\;$ is:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &=  -\dfrac{\cos t + 2\cos 2t}{\sin t + 2\sin 2t\ }
\end{align}

I don't know what to plug in for t, to get my slope. I know that $\,\frac{dy}{dx}\,$  is the slope, but what would go in for t? I solved a similar problem where they gave me the t and asked me to find the slope but I don't know how to handle this one.

Comment: try $t=\pi/2$...

Comment: Yeah but how did you get that

Comment: You have to solve $\cos(t)+\cos(2t)=-1$ and $\sin(t)+\sin(2t)=1$.

Comment: While the answer of Bye is of course algebraically the way to go, one can also make a quick graph. I used Desmos and let the angle go from 0 to 2pi. Looking at the "making" of the graph, it was easy to establish the t-value for (-1,1)